# Angular 1.5, ui-router + resource + components, stateProvider can't find component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, resources, components

My app has structure like:

```
app/
   js/
     levels/
           level-create
           level-edit
           level-list/
                     level-list.template.html
                     levellist.component.js
           level-show/
                     level-show.template.html
                     levelshow.component.js
     levels.module.js
```

also i have basic resource service which i inject to every component and route file:

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = angular
    .module('app.levels.route', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state({
            component: 'levellist',
            name: 'levelIndex',
            url: '/levels',
            template: '<levellist></levellist>'
        }).state({
            component: 'levelshow',
            name: 'levelShow',
            url: 'levels/:id',
            template: '<levelshow></levelshow>'
        });

    });
```

with levellist component all works fine, but with levelshow it just can't find this component... Also i've noticed that search engine of stateProvider component is very specific.
There are levelshow.component.js

```
    'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');

module.exports = angular
    .module('app.levelsshow.component', ['ngMaterial'])
    .component('levelshow', {
        controller: LevelShowController,
        templateUrl: '/app/js/levels/components/level-show/level-show.template.html'
    });

LevelShowController.$inject = ['Level', '$scope', '$stateParams'];

function LevelShowController(Level, $scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.levelShow = Level.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
}
```

Comment: What exaclty do you mean by 'crashes'? Some piece of log maybe?

Comment: You have a multi-module app here. Wouldn't you need to inject the levelshow's module `app.levelsshow.component` as dependency in `app.levels.route` ?

Comment: in my opinion route file can't find the next component levelshow, so it just don't show me any erros. I inject all of it in one module level.module.js. I require all of this files so it works with levellist.component.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the question is solwed. There is no need to mark the component tag in $stateProvider.state